# If I installed Emacs from package manager, where is the .emacs file, and how do I get Emacs to see it?

Tags: apt, mate, emacs, source, orca

I am completely blind and am currently in a job or internship where I have to use Emacs on a regular basis to learn *Lisp*. I was informed by other blind Linux users that Emacspeak would allow me to get around quite easily. I am using Ubuntu Mate for this setup on a virtual machine hosted on Windows.

I first started out by installing *emacs* and *emacspeak* using

```
sudo apt install.
```

I also had to install *espeak* and *espeak-ng* before installing Emacspeak, and then I had to run

```
dpkg-reconfigure emacspeak
```

a few times to switch the speech server until eSpeak finally responded. However, I didn't really like the voice, but one of my friends said I could purchase the [Voxin ViaVoice Outloud](https://voxin.oralux.net/) package, which I did. Upon completion of purchase, I downloaded the Tarball from the site onto my system and ran the

```
./voxin_installer.sh
```

script. I heard audible confirmation from ViaVoice that it was successfully installed, so I rebooted the VM for the changes to take effect.

I tried switching Emacspeak to Outloud via the *dpkg-reconfigure* method, but I didn't hear any speech output, so my friend recommended that I install Emacspeak from source. HTTP://github.com/tvraman/emacspeak

I followed the steps in the [article](https://tvraman.github.io/emacspeak/manual/Quick-Installation.html#Quick-Installation) and had to install several dependencies because

```
~/emacspeak/servers/linux-outloud
```

wasn't compiling properly. The dependencies I had to install were

- build-essential
- tcl
- tcl.h
- tcl8.6-dev
- tk
- tclx
- libasound2-dev

I verified this by running *./servers/outloud* and typing *q "this is a test" d* and I heard what it said with *ViaVoice.*

The instructions say to add

```
(load-file "&lt;emacspeak-dir&gt;/lisp/emacspeak-setup.el")
```

to the top of my *.emacs* file, but I can't find *.emacs* or *.emacs.el* file anywhere, not even in my home directory.

I am assuming it is because  I installed Emacs from the package manager rather than from source, so I tried following the steps [here](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_emacs_installation/) but I cannot download any of the dependencies when running

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs27.1
```

the latest version of Emacs. It says that you must have a source URI in sources.list. I enabled the source code option under *Software and Updates*, and I think it asked for a main server or something.
One thing I noticed was that Emacs from Apt is version 25, but the latest version is 27, which I added using PPA.

UPDATE: I rebuilt this virtual machine and started making backups in case something went wrong. In the first backup, I built Emacspeak from source. In the next snapshot, I installed Emacspeak from apt. When I launched *emacspeak*, I heard ViaVoice say, 'ViaVoice using ALSA.' It only spoke what I typed on the keyboard, though, not what was on the screen when I pressed *C-n* or *C-p*.

Even though Emacspeak seems to work pretty well with eSpeak, I have some trouble understanding it because I also have some hearing loss, and ViaVoice seems to have better clarity.

So now it's a question of telling the Emacs package where *.emacs.el* is, so that it can properly execute the

```
(load-file "/home/user/emacspeak/lis/emacspeak-setup.el")
```

Right now, when I run *emacs*, no speech is heard, other than Orca saying, "Emacs 25 Frame: dummy text.'

If someone can find a possible solution, I would greatly appreciate it. My mentor suggested that I use *C-h v* and type *user-init-file* to locate the .emacs.el file. It was indeed created in */home/heavenlyharmony/.emacs.el*

He also suggested I add the load-file code to */home/heavenlyharmony/.emacs.d/init.el*, but that didn't work.

Comment: You create the `.emacs` file in your home directory. Packages don't mess about in user home directories, so you have to do that yourself.

Comment: So now it's a question of the `.emacs` syntax, since Emacs itself is loading the `.emacs` file now. I don't know that syntax, so hopefully someone else can help with that.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote exactly `(load-file "/home/harmony1994/emacspeak/lisp/emacspeak-setup.el")` (parentheses included?). With that line, I get the expected error that `/home/harmony1994/emacspeak/lisp/emacspeak-setup.el` is missing, not that `load-file` itself is missing.

Comment: I found a similar question on this site, but the answer is a little confusing. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26821/file-error-cannot-open-load-file

Comment: I rebuilt my virtual machine this time and created *.emacs* and *.emacs.el* with the line, but starting *emacs* just says Emacs 25 frame, dummy text.

Comment: Does running with `emacs -q -l /home/harmony1994/emacspeak/lisp/emacspeak-setup.el` work? The [source](https://github.com/tvraman/emacspeak/blob/550ada17b948d0ddc93296df8d61e91cd2445a5f/lisp/emacspeak-setup.el#L44) recommends checking that first.

Comment: I didn't hear any speech output, but I did use Windows OCR to get this message. emacs@ubuntu
File Edit Options Buffers Tools Lisp-Interaction Help
Thu Jan 28, 01:50
scratch
Process S eaker not runnin
harmony1994@ubuntu:- e and S mboVs function definition
harmony1994@ubuntu:- e
n e rac on
is void: make-thread
emacs@ubuntu